# How do i do a left join of two tables and exclude out the row with max count

Tags: join, count, max

```
Create View ServicePopularityView AS
SELECT dog.petId,
       dog.petName AS [name],
       dog.petBreed AS [breed],
       dog.petDateOfBirth AS [date of birth],
       dog.petGender AS [gender],
       dog.ownerId,
       count(groomingHistory.serviceId) AS [count]
FROM dog
LEFT JOIN groomingHistory ON dog.petId= groomingHistory.petId
GROUP BY dog.petId,
         dog.petName,
         dog.petBreed,
         dog.petDateOfBirth,
         dog.petGender,
         dog.ownerId;
```

I have tried multiple ways i found online but it has always given me aggregate errors or cannot use certain clause.

I wish to find a way to left join the `tables` leaving me without the `row` that has the most common `serviceId` used.

There are also multiple `"dogs"` that share each service.

I am a beginner at this.

Comment: can you format that better?

Comment: write a query to find the petId excluded row and add the clause "and dog.petId not in ..."

Comment: May i know where do i place that. Select portion? From? On?

Answer (score 0):

```
Create View ServicePopularityView AS
SELECT dog.petId,
       dog.petName AS [name],
       dog.petBreed AS [breed],
       dog.petDateOfBirth AS [date of birth],
       dog.petGender AS [gender],
       dog.ownerId,
       count(groomingHistory.serviceId) AS [count]
FROM dog
LEFT JOIN groomingHistory ON dog.petId = groomingHistory.petId
GROUP BY dog.petId,
         dog.petName,
         dog.petBreed,
         dog.petDateOfBirth,
         dog.petGender,
         dog.ownerId;
HAVING count(groomingHistory.serviceId) <
       (SELECT TOP 1 count(groomingHistory.serviceId)
        FROM dog
        LEFT JOIN groomingHistory ON dog.petId = groomingHistory.petId
        GROUP BY dog.petId,
                 dog.petName,
                 dog.petBreed,
                 dog.petDateOfBirth,
                 dog.petGender,
                 dog.ownerId
        ORDER BY count(groomingHistory.serviceId) DESC)
```

Comment: It omits the results of the dogs that uses the most service but not the dogs that uses the most common service